# Why are these wierd characters being inserted in Facebook iframe when using jQuery? â€‹

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, facebook, facebook-iframe

jQuery parses some html in my iframe app on Facebook, and when it does, I get tons of these characters:

â€‹ â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹

Please see screenshot for more info. Does anyone know why this occurring! and how to fix it?

[screenshot showing problem - note how it is randomly inserted into inline css too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIJFp.jpg)

Comment: Impossible to tell without code, but generally that kind of stuff is due to encoding issues.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt in the doctype declaration? Which code should i provide?

Comment: You were right. I cleaned up the top of the doc with encoding info and it works.

Comment: I added an answer so you can accept if it fixed your problem :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an encoding issue, probably. You'll probably want to define the `charset`. Like this:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Comment: I also found it could be down to the file itself, or the text/characters within the file. My solution was to copy the code block by block into a fresh new file. Try doing Plain Text copy (Or use Terminal/Notepad) to be on the safe side. The issue then disappeared for me. My related issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427080/why-is-%C3%A2%E2%82%AC-or-8203-being-inserted-into-my-html-body-randomly